# Portal Users not able to access custom object

Tags: customer-portal, custom-object

Our Sales rep set up High Volume Customer Portal Licenses for us and they work in the sandbox just fine but in production the profiles dont have access to any of the customer objects?

All of the objects are marked as "available in customer portal"  but when i edit the profile for the High Volume customer portal or try to make a new customer profile using that license all i see is Standard Object Permissions, Custom object permissions doesnt even show as an option?

am I missing a checkbox somewhere?

Here is some screen shots of the profile edit screen, the exact same screen in both.

Production: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2128262/production.png

Sandbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2128262/sandbox.png

And here is the top part so you can see the license type: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2128262/license_type.png

Comment: Once you clone High Volume portal profile you will surely can access Custom object permissions .Try cloning the profile of high volume customer portal

Comment: i did that, its still not there

Comment: Stumped!!Seriously no idea now

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the permissions of the profile?  Can you check cloning a standard profile to make sure the custom settings are there?

Comment: Here is some screen shots of the profile edit screen, the exact same screen in both.

Production: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2128262/production.png
Sandbox: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2128262/sandbox.png

And here is the top part so you can see the license type: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2128262/license_type.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double-check the 'Available for Customer Portal' checkbox on these objects in your Production environment. What you describe is exactly what occurs without this box checked.

- Are these managed package objects?
- Did you deploy the entirety of the metadata of these objects to production?

If it's already been resolved, can you provide the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Raise a case with Salesforce. This should be visible.

Comment: already done, hopefully they can fix it.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry everyone.  Turns out I was wrong, I swore I had checked the "Available for customer portal" but it wasnt checked after all.

What a dummy I am, once I checked it everything worked fine..

Sorry for all the confusion everyone!

It should be noted for anyone dealing with this issue this seems to be a setting that doesnt deploy from the sandbox.  It seems like you have to manually go and check it for any new custom object after you deploy